# How to disable kerberos replay cache in Java?

Tags: java, kerberos

I found that define the environment variable KRB5RCACHETYPE=none can disable kerberos replay cache in c/c++ applications, Java has it's own implementation of kerberos authentication, does anyone know how to disable replay cache in Java?

Comment: Probably by using useTicketCache=false as per http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/security/jgss/single-signon.html

Comment: Thanks Usman, but useTicketCache has nothing to do with replay cache

Comment: Why do you want to disable the replay detection anyway?

Answer (score 2):

I would disable replay detection: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/org/ietf/jgss/GSSContext.html#requestReplayDet%28boolean%29

Comment: Michael-O - my requirement is to use the same kerberos ticket received from client (in my case, browser), to be passed to multiple modules, each module verifies the ticket on its own. Currently "Request is a replay (34)" error is thrown on calling "context.acceptSecContext" twice on the same ticket. Any hints are highly appreciated.

Comment: @BhushanKarmarkar, your approach does not make any sense and should not be done. Have your user authenticated and pass on his `Principal`.

Comment: Please explain me if you can why it should not be done. I am simply exploring the things and open for change.
In my case, individual modules establish the connection with third party kerberized systems. My plan is to pass the same ticket to every module. Assume that the modules are deployed in another JVM or container.
I can not consume (context.accept) the ticket in advance because its simply out of scope and also the GSS credentials (such as delegated or impersonated GSS credentials) are not serializable.

Comment: @BhushanKarmarkar Then you have to authenticate separately to each and every module. If you cannot perform credential delegation you should look into S4U2self. Note that MIT Kerberos supports serialization of credentials.

Comment: Thanks @Michael-O, I will take a look.
Isn't the GSS API common for MIT and Microsoft implementations of kerberos?

Comment: @BhushanKarmarkar, correct. There are different flavors of.